# How to make aplications installed in /opt appear in Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher, libreoffice

Libreoffice 3.4 was installed in /opt and a link to the executable was put in /usr/bin, but Unity search can't find it. Also, if I open Libreoffice Writer, for instance, and ask to keep its icon in launcher, it doesn't work afterwards.

Comment: was this link a .desktop file?

Comment: This has been answered in http://askubuntu.com/questions/51194/how-to-make-the-unity-app-search-find-a-manually-installed-app/51198#51198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can try creating a laucher icon. Do the following:

Right-click on your desktop and select Create Laucher option:

[image]

A dialog box is going to prompt. You may now set up your laucher.
[image]

By clicking on the *Browse* button you may select the file to be executed. (in this case, google chrome)
[image]

Having everything set, click *OK* and a new laucher will be added to your desktop folder.
[image]

Now, you may cut and paste it wherever you want, as well as drag and drop it to your Unity bar (whateverthenameofthiscrapis).

[image]