# mismatch between installed versions of pycharm in launcher

Tags: launcher, icons

My problem is as follows:

I had pycharm 2016 installed and its icon appeared in the launcher. When I wanted to update to 2017, I downloaded the file from their website and installed it, thinking that it would automatically overwrite version 2016. It was not the case.

I did not mind so much, and I was always running the executable file of version 2017 from the folder I downloaded.

Now problem comes when I updated directly from pycharm to version 2018. I can't find where is the executable file (`whereis` and `which` won't work since it's not a dpkg package, and `find . pycharm*` prompts thousands of results. in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/share/` there is no pycharm either).

I neither can do this ([How to make aplications installed in /opt appear in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51234/how-to-make-aplications-installed-in-opt-appear-in-unity/51236#51236)) cause right click in desktop does nothing.

I would like to remove older versions of pycharm and create a new icon for the new one, once I find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a workaround, but finally I downloaded the tar file for the 2018 version, and modified the `.desktop` file using that `.sh` file.